# how to take multiple selectbox values and push into string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, angularjs

I am using a multiselect box. I need to be able to add and remove values and create a comma separated string array.

I made a plunker. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7rSLJuJqtJT7nTyQs6gN?p=preview)

```
 var msaskArray = [];
    $scope.$watch("MSASK", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            msaskArray.push(newValue)
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(msaskArray))
    });
```

I have attached a screenshot of the result I am currently getting. 
[image: pic]

The result I need should look like this

> ["9,14,18"]

Comment: Initialize the array every time a selection is made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `multiple` attribute in plunkr that will allow you to select multiple options.

No need to put `$watch` on the `MASK` variable at all. You could easily use out `$scope.MASK` whenever you needed it. Also use `ng-change` directive to get fire scope function on change event of the select box.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-options="m.MSASK as m.Market_Name for m in markets" 
 ng-model="MSASK" multiple></select>
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qPs8unUZ313MTrBv8hJN?p=preview%5C)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it looks like you need to just clear  the first ones.:

```
var msaskArray = [];
    $scope.$watch("MSASK", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            msaskArray = [];
            msaskArray.push(newValue)
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(msaskArray))
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug your javascript and look at your newValue it looks like it is already an array. And it's already doing what you want. You now have a 2 dimensional array.